# Path to a file on my JBoss server from a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, jboss, path

I have a csv file attached to my project on Eclipse and this project have a servlet which is deployed on a local JBoss server for development.

I want to access this csv file and I can using the absolute path on my computer, like this:

```
CSVExtractor csvE = new CSVExtractor("C:/workspace/myproject/WebContent/data.csv");
```

The problem with that approach is tha it's not portable in any ways. I believe JBoss my supply a method so I can get access to files inside my project but I didn't find it. What would be the prefered method?

PS: I also believe it's a bad practice to put a file like this in my WebContent folder, what's the best way to isolate this kind of stuff from the user?

Answer (score 0):

Add it to your classpath (WEB-INF/classes or lib) and access it as a classpath resource. Here is an [example](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4480). Classpath resources are portable unlike as they are bundled with the deployment archive itself.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-08/01-qa-0808-property.html) for you to get started.

Comment: When you say "add it to /WEB-INF/lib" you mean just putting the data.csv in that folder? I've made this, but I can't figure what's the path right now. Is it /myproject/WEB-INF/lib/data.csv? Am I missing something?

Comment: @ThiagoMoraes move it to classes. Read the tutorial i've added

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a properties file that specified a directory. This would allow your users to modify both the directory and hot swap the .csv without redeploying the archive.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    String path = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("language/file.xml").getPath();

    File f = new File(path);

    System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```